# Linux Mint hotkeys: how to use pipes and redirects?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

**How to use redirectors and built-in shell functions in hotkey commands?** 
I'm using the following line to grep in anacrontab, and kick-off an system update Ansible playbook:
[image: hotkey]

**redirectors**
I'm wondering why lines with a pipe (|) do not work: `echo piping | logger`. No error is shown. Instead `logger hi` can do the job in this example. How come this happens? Is there another way to use redirectors?

**build-in shell functions**
There is an error message for bash build-in shell functions such as read.
[image: read] 

*Translation: Execution of child process `read` failed (File or folder does not exist)*

Hope someone could explain what actually happens when a hotkey command is invoked :). And point out an alternative.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/, and a translation of the messages would also be helpful, as most people around here don't speak dutch.

Comment: Did you try enclosing the command in double quotes? `"echo piping | logger"`

Comment: Hey slimmerik, niet iedereen spreekt hier Nederlands ... (for those who don't understand dutch/Flemish: hey, not everybody speaks Dutch around here ...). Hurry to translate it all to English, and do not use "images" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sh -c 'command1 | command2'`

Comment: Got what I wanted using: 
```bash -c "$(grep -P --color -o '(?<=system-maintenance.daily).*' /etc/anacrontab | sh -)"```
Thank you so much :).